# TypeError: with_column() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given (python)

Tags: python, jupyter

I have been having issue with the limits of positional arguments in jupyter notebook.
Im trying to To get a sense of the variability in the number of heads in 100 tosses, we can collect the results in a table and draw a histogram.

```
         simulation_results = Table().with_column(
        'Repetition', np.arange(1, num_repetitions + 1),
        'Number of Heads', heads
    )
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-484d76c43683> in <module>
    ----> 1 simulation_results = Table().with_column(
          2     'Repetition', np.arange(1, num_repetitions + 1),
          3     'Number of Heads', heads
          4 )
    
    TypeError: with_column() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question actually is. Your call has the wrong number of arguments, that's what the error says. In case that's the source of your confusion, there is another hidden parameter `self` in the call. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, try to reduce the code in question to something like a [mcve], because people here don't know your context (and guessing is bad) and it also makes it easier for you to understand.

Comment: What is `Table`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Table is from [datascience](http://data8.org/datascience/tables.html) package

Comment: @bvamos How do you know? I don't see any clues for that in the question...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I just know the [source of this code](https://www.inferentialthinking.com/chapters/09/3/Simulation.html)

Comment: @bvamos My point was that you maybe recognized but others might not. My comment was more directed to the OP and not to you. This kind of information should be [edit]ed into the question...

Answer (score 0):

[with_column()](http://data8.org/datascience/_autosummary/datascience.tables.Table.with_column.html#datascience.tables.Table.with_column) can add or replace only one column at a time, so rewrite it to:

```
simulation_results = Table().with_column(
  'Repetition', np.arange(1, num_repetitions + 1)
)
simulation_results = simulation_results.with_column(
  'Number of Heads', heads
)
```

or

```
simulation_results = Table()
.with_column('Repetition', np.arange(1, num_repetitions + 1))
.with_column('Number of Heads', heads)
```